# Easier way to call same method for multiple variables

Tags: java

Is it possible to not have to re type all of these almost identical procedures?

```
cancelSaveContactBtn.setVisible(false);
saveContactBtn.setVisible(false);
addContactBtn.setVisible(true);
```

and

```
selectContactCBox.addActionListener(this);
addContactBtn.addActionListener(this);
personalRadio.addActionListener(this);
businessRadio.addActionListener(this);
```

Answer (score 3):

Technically if you intend to call the same method with the same parameter on a set of objects you could use a List to store your objects, iterate through and set an `addActionListener` to each one.

```
List<Object> objects = new ArrayList<Object>();

objects.add(selectContactCBox);
objects.add(addContactBtn);
objects.add(personalRadio);
objects.add(businessRadio);

for(object o: objects){
o.addActionListener(this);
}
```